# Lucene search on multiple fields but match on any

Tags: java, lucene

I'm currently trying to create a query where I can search on 4 fields but return the document where it matches any field.

Can someone tell me how to set this up please. I've tried BooleanQuery and MultiFieldQueryParser but I can't get any hits.

```
    BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
    Query query1 = new TermQuery(new Term("field1", text1));
    Query query2 = new TermQuery(new Term("field2", text2));
    Query query3 = new TermQuery(new Term("field3", text3));
    Query query4 = new TermQuery(new Term("field4", text4));
    booleanQuery.add(query1, Occur.SHOULD);
    booleanQuery.add(query2, Occur.SHOULD);
    booleanQuery.add(query3, Occur.SHOULD);
    booleanQuery.add(query4, Occur.SHOULD);


    MultiFieldQueryParser multiQueryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_44, 
            new String[] {"field1", "field2", "field3", "field4"}, analyzer);

    multiQueryParser.setDefaultOperator(Operator.OR);
```

I was getting results with multiQueryParser with the operator set to AND however I don't get anything with OR. Results were only returned when 2 fields matched, I think.

Can someone please sugguest what is wrong?

Thanks

And to add, I looking for partial matches or either full matches.

Full code:

public class Demo {

```
IndexWriter indexWriter = null;

public boolean openIndex() {
    try {
        Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexerPath));
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_44);
        IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_44, analyzer);
        indexWriter = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);
        isIndexOpen = true;
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public void finish() {
    try {
        indexWriter.close();
        isIndexOpen = false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

@Override
public void addDoc(MyObject obj) {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("field1", obj.getField1(), Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("field2", obj.getField2(),, Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("field3", obj.getField3(),, Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("field4", obj.getField4(),, Field.Store.YES));

    try {
        indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}

@Override
public void getResults(String text) throws ParseException, IOException {
    Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexerPath));
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(dir);
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_44);

    MultiFieldQueryParser multiQueryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_44, 
            new String[] {"field1", "field2", "field3", "field4"}, analyzer);

    multiQueryParser.setDefaultOperator(Operator.OR);
    Query query = multiQueryParser.parse(text);
    searcher.search(query, collector);
    hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;

    for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; ++i) {
        int docId = hits[i].doc;
        Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
        Log.info("\f1: "+d.get("field1") + " f2: " + d.get("field2") + 
                " f3: "+d.get("field3") + " f4: "+ d.get("field3"));
    }

    return results;
}
```

}

Comment: Both of your queries seem OK. Can you provide a self-contained example with `IndexWriter` showing how you add documents and what are you searching against (I refer to `text1`, ... `text4`)? Note: if you want partial matches, you need to use wildcards, e.g. `text1*`.

Comment: Sorry text1-4 is the same word. 
    Document keyDoc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("field1", str1, Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("field2", str2.getIntexDealName(), Field.Store.YES));
  doc.add(new TextField("field3", str3.getBbDealNameShort(), Field.Store.YES));
  doc.add(new TextField("field4", str4, Field.Store.YES));

Comment: IndexWriter is created with using IndexWriterConfig and using the StandardAnalyzer.  Basically when I used the multiFieldParser I'm only seem to be getting results when 2 fields match. I would like to return hits when there is a match one 1 or more fields.

Comment: Could it be that lucene is not returning hits for small query. For example if I search the full text of a field I do get a hit back, but if I remove one character from the search I get none back.

How can I return hits even if I type one or 2 characters?

Comment: Every of these problems ("if I remove one character") you need to explain in your question. Best explained in code :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Self-contained example* means code which compiles and relies on no external resource to run/demonstrate the problem. Your code doesn't.

Here is modified version of your code which works and demonstrates partial matches.

```
public class Demo {

    static Directory dir;

    IndexWriter indexWriter;

    public boolean openIndex() {
        try {
            dir = new RAMDirectory();
            Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_44);
            IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_44, analyzer);
            indexWriter = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void finish() {
        try {
            indexWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addDoc() {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new TextField("field1", "val1", Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new TextField("field2", "val2", Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new TextField("field3", "val3", Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new TextField("field4", "val4", Field.Store.YES));

        try {
            indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
            indexWriter.commit();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void printResults(Query query) throws IOException {
        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(dir);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        TopDocs result = searcher.search(query, 5);
        System.out.println("# of results:" + result.totalHits);
        for (ScoreDoc doc : result.scoreDocs) {
            System.out.println(doc);
        }

        reader.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        demo.openIndex();
        demo.addDoc();
        demo.finish();


        BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
        Query query1 = new TermQuery(new Term("field1", "val1"));
        Query query2 = new TermQuery(new Term("field2", "val2"));
        Query query3 = new TermQuery(new Term("field3", "val3"));
        Query query4 = new TermQuery(new Term("field4", "val4"));
        booleanQuery.add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
        booleanQuery.add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
        booleanQuery.add(query3, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
        booleanQuery.add(query4, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
        printResults(booleanQuery);

        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_44);
        MultiFieldQueryParser multiQueryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_44,
                    new String[] {"field1", "field2", "field3", "field4"}, analyzer);
        multiQueryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.OR);

        Query mfQuery = multiQueryParser.parse("field1:val1 field2:val2 field3:val3 field4:val4");
        printResults(mfQuery);

        Query mfQuery2 = multiQueryParser.parse("field1:val* field2:x field3:y field4:z");
        printResults(mfQuery2);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I did not realize that for partial results I need the *, I was confused as without the * I was still getting some partial query matches but not always. This is what got me puzzled. Thank you.